# Family Sharing apps in iOS

Tags: ios-appstore, family-sharing

I've set up the new Family Sharing in iOS. How do I go about sharing a specific app from one Iphone to another?
Do I need to use iTunes on the desktop?
Does it depend upon whether the developer has approved sharing?
The app I wish to share is this one:

Theory Test and Hazard Perception Pro by Deep River Development Ltd
https://appsto.re/gb/rYTHJ.i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've set up Family Sharing, everyone can access each others' apps, music, movies, TV shows and books.

To download content from another family member, sign into your iTunes account and visit the "Purchased" pages in the iTunes store, iBook store or App Store. Simply choose the family member whose content you want, and go ahead and download.

Comment: Thanks - will try that.  I assumed you had to "send" it from the original owner's device...